# Should a table containing couples of rows from another table with similar attribute contain that data?

Tags: sql, relational-database, database-normalization, redundancy

lets say we have a table of people, and the country theyre from.

and we have a table of couples, each row has to people, and every couple will always belong to the same country.

do we want to save the country on the couples table?
will this count as normalized? redundant?

Comment: The Couples table should have the Id of the Person.  The Person table has the country they're from, according to the first sentence.  HOWEVER, part of the answer to this question depends on the purpose of the tables and how they will be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce the rule that couples must belong to the same country, you can include `country` in the `couples` table. See my answer to [How to preserve data integrity in circular reference database structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764009/how-to-preserve-data-integrity-in-circular-reference-database-structure/48784870#48784870) for a similar situation and an example of how to implement this.

The `country` column in the `couples` table would be logically redundant and violate 2NF (assuming the table has the identifiers of the two persons as a primary or unique key) but the method of overlapping foreign key constraints eliminate the risk of data anomalies.